# If, then statements in R

Tags: r, if-statement, pipe

I am teaching myself R and trying to figure out how to properly write an if, then statement. I have a df of demographic data and I want to create a variable for highest degree in the household, based on marital status. If the data is coded a 0, 3, or 7, it is a single-parent (mom) household and then would use the mother's degree. But, if it's 1, 2, 4, 5, or 6, I want to use the highest of either caregiver's education.

```
> ExcelData <-df
> marital <- c(1, 0, 1, 5, 7, 2, NA, 1)
> education <- c("10", "12", "13", "14", "16", "18", "12", "14")
> education_partner <- c("11", "18", "10", "14", "11", "12", "16", "16")
```

i wrote this and it works, creating a new df with maternal education, but I'm not sure how to write it where it prints the greater value of education or education_partner when it is a 1, 2, 4, 5, or 6. any advice is greatly appreciated!!

```
if(ExcelData$marital =  0 | 3:7 )
  hhHighestDegree <- (ExcelData$education)
```

Comment: What is `df` in `ExcelData <-df` ? Can you show your expected output for this example ?

Answer (score 0):

`if/else` is not vectorized.  We may either use `ifelse` or create a logical vector and then assign the subset of the 'education' column based on the logical vector to a new object 'hhHighestDegree'.

Based on the code showed, we need to extract the 'education' values where the 'marital' values are either 0 or from 3:7.  So, we can use `%in%` to create logical vector (`%in%` will also return `FALSE` for `NA` values unlike comparison operators (`>`, `<`, `==`)

```
i1 <- ExcelData$marital %in% c(0, 3:7)
hhHighestDegree <- ExcelData$education[i1]
```

---

Or if we prefer to use `>` with `|`

```
i1 <- with(ExcelData, (marital == 0| (marital >=3 & marital<=7)) & 
            !is.na(marital))
hhHighestDegree <- ExcelData$education[i1]
```

#### data

```
ExcelData <- structure(list(marital = c(1, 0, 1, 5, 7, 2, NA, 1), 
education = c("10", 
"12", "13", "14", "16", "18", "12", "14"), education_partner = c("11", 
"18", "10", "14", "11", "12", "16", "16")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response, akrun, I appreciate you! so i'm following along with what you said (i think), but is there a way that R would know to create an output of either the education variable or the education_partner variable (whichever is higher)? i know that FALSE is used instead of NA but my other output is TRUE. thank you again for all the help!

Comment: @lziegs Both seems to be charaacter vectors?  You need it as numeric, then we use `with(ExcelData, pmax(as.numeric(education), as.numeric(education_partner)))`